# How to use Aggregation along with group by and sum

Tags: mongodb, laravel, aggregation-framework

How to get the sum of purchased deal's `price` (current year data) group by week, day, year using `purchased_at` field

My collection data:

```
{
"_id": ObjectId("5a66d619042e9f3a070d6864"),
"name": "Deal1",
"price": "2000",
"status": true,
"purchased_at": ISODate("2018-01-23T06:28:41.0Z")
}
{
"_id": ObjectId("5a66d619042e9f3a070d6872"),
"name": "Deal2",
"price": "500",
"status": true,
"purchased_at": ISODate("2018-01-13T06:28:41.0Z")
}
{
"_id": ObjectId("5a66d619042e9f3a070d6880"),
"name": "Deal3",
"price": "1000",
"status": true,
"purchased_at": ISODate("2018-02-13T06:28:41.0Z")
}
{
"_id": ObjectId("5a66d619042e9f3a070d6880"),
"name": "Deal4",
"price": "1000",
"status": false,
"purchased_at": ISODate("2018-01-11T06:28:41.0Z")
}
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: Can you add the expected json output to the post ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using non standard date format, you need to use `filter()`:

```
$lastWeekSum = $collection->filter(function($i) {
    Carbon::parse($i['purchased_at'])->gt(now()->subWeek());
})->sum('price');
```

If `$i['purchased_at']` returns an object, you should convert it to a string like `2018-01-11T06:28:41.0Z` before parsing it.

Comment: I have to build a sales graph, so need each week data.